# Use ID in php if

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a problem with JavaScript and php. I use countdown timer with JavaScript and when its time over, html div id content switch "EXPIRED".

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
<?php 

$sount=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dates");
$count->execute();
$row=$count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$date = $row['acik_tarih'];
$h = $row['acik_saat'];
$m = $row['acik_dakika'];
$s = $row['acik_saniye'];

?>
<script>
 var countDownDate = <?php 
echo strtotime("$date $h:$m:$s" ) ?> * 1000;
var now = <?php echo strtotime($row['start']) ?> * 1000;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {
now = now + 1000;
// Find the distance between now an the count down date
var distance = countDownDate - now;
// Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
// Output the result in an element with id="demo"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h" +
minutes + "m" + seconds + "s";
// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance < 0) {
clearInterval(x);
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}
    
}, 1000);

    </script>
```

You can see id demo switch EXPIRED when time is over.

I use `<div id="demo"></div>` for results.

There is no problem so far. But i want chance something if times over. Here is my question; how am i use php if when id="demo" reult is expired.
For example:

```
<?php if (#id=="EXPIRED") { ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="#" class="btnMgn primary-btn text-uppercase mx-auto d-block">OFFER</a>

    <?php } ?>
```

I know this php code doesn't work as this is just a random example but you can understand what I mean. How can I use this? Or can I do that?

Comment: You do realise that PHP only runs on the server, dont you? If you are in the browser running JS code then its to late to run PHP unless you go back to the server either via a form submit of maybe you want a AJAX call to requested the server provides you some info. But as you dont do anything server related, why not do this in Javascript as well

Comment: Actually i don't know javascript very well but thank you for your answer i will do research to do it with AJAX